# Téléchargement de fichier - File Upload

Tags: software-installation

I am a new Linux user. I have BR-OS version 23.04. I'm a little lost as to how to use it, especially when it comes to downloading files and installing applications. Can you explain to me how this works? If I'm not in the right place for questions, please tell me where to go?

Comment: Ce site utilise uniquement l'anglais.

Comment: BR-OS is not an official Ubuntu flavour and not supported here. However, before asking such generic questions you should definitely do some research by yourself first. The answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/307280/590937) should be helpful for you.

Comment: I do reserch and I don't find by myself. So I ask for help!